# Acknowledgment to friend in research article

Tags: publications

I have a research article that has been accepted in reputed journal and is in final stage of publication. Now I want add acknowledgment in my article, as I independently written this article so nobody has academically contributed to my research. But I strongly believe that my research could been effected very badly if my close friend had not been there for my help(not academic of-course).

Can I add his name in acknowledgment?

Comment: I know someone who always acknowledges the help and support of his wife in his articles (or at least when the journal allows it, but I've seen it on about 5 of his papers).

Answer (score 3):

This sort of thing is quite normal in books. In articles, one frequently sees the author(s) thanking a colleague for fruitful discussions and such. If you really feel so strongly about your friend's impact on your work, I think it would be perfectly appropriate to include it. Just avoid specifics such as "X helped me deal with the effects of my depression and drug dependency". (In other words, use common sense.)

Comment: Phrases like " ... for helpful discussions" are useful here.

Answer (score 2):

Some journals expressly forbid acknowledgements for assistance that is not related to the substance of an article.  That would mean funders are OK, colleagues you discussed the work with are OK, but somebody who only provided emotional or personal support would not be.  So you ought to check the submission guidelines for the journal you are interested in.  If it doesn't mention anything, then I would conclude that are purely personal acknowledgement should be fine, but it should be kept brief.

For longer works like books, this should certainly be fine as well.  Personal thanks are commonplace in academic textbooks and monographs.

Answer (score 1):

You can thanking anyone (besides grant provider and maybe lab technicians) in acknowledgment because that section is not related to your manuscript. This is particularly true if you think him/her contributing much to your research but not as crucial as to put them as co-authors.